# Displaying image from ForeignKey in Admin Panel in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have in project two classes - ***Photo*** and ***Prescription*** inside **models.py** file which are related each other with foreign key. Here is part of the code:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/",null=True) 

    def photo_tag(self):
        return '<a href="/media/{0}"><img src="/media/{0}"></a>'.format(self.photo)
    photo_tag.short_description = 'Photo of prescription'
    photo_tag.allow_tags = True


class Prescription(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='related_photo',null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

And my **Admin.py**

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'photo_tag')
    fields = ('name','photo','photo_tag')     
    readonly_fields = ('photo_tag',)
admin.site.register(Photo,PhotoAdmin)

class PrescriptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_photo')
    fields = ('photo','description')
    model = Prescription

    def get_photo(self, obj):
        return obj.photo.photo_tag
    get_photo.short_description = 'Photo of prescription'
admin.site.register(Prescription,PrescriptionAdmin)
```

Question is, when I open prescriptions list instead of photo in the **Photo of prescription** field shows following message.

```
<bound method Photo.photo_tag of <Photo: Photo object>>
```

How real photo could be described there?

Comment: You forgot to *call* the `photo_tag` method.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely? Where exactly I should put it?

Comment: If you mean in the `get_photo` function instead of `return obj.photo.photo_tag` use `return obj.photo.photo_tag()`, I have also tried it. In that case I got that for example
**<a href="/media/photos/carousel-drevena-kuchynka-na-hrani-02-03_1.jpg"><img src="/media/photos/carousel-drevena-kuchynka-na-hrani-02-03_1.jpg"></a>**

Comment: And that is, let me guess the HTML code you actually want to have in your page, just quoted and therefor displayed. You have to [mark it as safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe).

Comment: Exactly after your first comment I remembered actually I have already met such situation and how I solve it when I saw HTML code instead of actual photo. It was safe command in html. So what I did? Just changed  `return obj.photo.photo_tag()` in **admin.py** and return line for `get_photo` function in **models.py** to `return mark_safe('<a href="/media/{0}"><img src="/media/{0}"></a>'.format(self.photo))` and imported `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe` library in order to use. And it worked. Thanks for giving idea to use method :). Actually it helped me to figure out mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks anybody who tried to help. I figured out another solution with help of @Klaus who answered first and I am pretty sure that there is maybe much more better solutions also. Here are how I changed my code

**Models.py**

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/",null=True) 

    def photo_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<a href="/media/{0}"><img src="/media/{0}"></a>'.format(self.photo))
    photo_tag.short_description = 'Photo of prescription'
    photo_tag.allow_tags = True


class Prescription(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='related_photo',null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

**Admin.py**

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'photo_tag')
    fields = ('name','photo','photo_tag')     
    readonly_fields = ('photo_tag',)
admin.site.register(Photo,PhotoAdmin)

class PrescriptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_photo')
    fields = ('photo','description')
    model = Prescription

    def get_photo(self, obj):
        return obj.photo.photo_tag()
    get_photo.short_description = 'Photo of prescription'
admin.site.register(Prescription,PrescriptionAdmin)
```

Comment: I wrote you to use `format_html`. Please read the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.html. It  advises to use `format_html` over `mark_safe`.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider your advice. And why `format_html` better than `mark_safe`?

Comment: The documentation explains that - it protects you against Cross Site Scripting (XSS). The `ImageField` is basically a string saved in the database. What if someone uploads this kind of string `<script>do_something_evil();</script>` instead of image? It's just theory, but you better be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

There are few wrong issues with your approach. Your `photo_tag` method should be a property method, or eventually `cached_property` method. For displaying safely HTML code you should use the method `format_html` provided by Django.

Here is how I'd refactor your code:

**`models.py`**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/", null=True)
    # better use blank=True instead of null=True for ImageField

    @cached_property
    def photo_tag(self):
        if self.photo:
            return format_html(
                '<a href="{img}"><img src="{img}"></a>',
                img=self.photo.url
            )
        return None # or better return '' if you use blank=True
    photo_tag.short_description = 'Photo of prescription'


class Prescription(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='related_photo', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Now you can use `photo_tag` as a property of `Photo` and bind the HTML safe in your admin.

Comment: Since your `ImageField` is optional, I added if-clause to handle this. However it would be better to use `blank=True`, instead of `null=True` for `ImageField` as it is basically a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to render the image in html (which I guess you are), could you not then use ginger to display the description in a similar way to this?

```
<img src="{{photo.url}" title="{{photo.short_description}}" alt="{{photo.short_description}}">
```

Note that I included the alt for internet explorer which seems to use that instead of title.

Comment: Great tip, especially, regarding internet explorer. Thanks ;)